# Why is $.get not returning the meta elements?

Tags: jquery

```
$.get('home.html', function(data) { 
  console.log($(data).find('meta')); // Doesnt work
  console.log($(data).find('#foobar')); // Works
});
```

Doesn't return the meta elements? What trickery is this?

Comment: `$("meta")` works on this very SO page. Are you sure `$(data)` includes `<meta>` elements?

Comment: But `$("<html><head><meta/></head></html>")` returns only the `meta` tag, and `$("<html><head><meta/></head></html>").find("meta")` finds nothing. jQuery looks like it strips the `<html>`/`<head>`? As this works `$("<div><meta/></div>").find("meta")`

Comment: Try doing it via an ajax response like `$.get()`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hmmmm, this seems a bit odd. But this works using `filter` instead of `find`.

```
$.get('home.html', function(data) { 
  console.log($(data).filter('meta')); // Now works
  console.log($(data).find('#foobar')); // Works
});
```

Comment: Think that's because filter works at the 'top-level' and find works on child elements. As in the other comment, find works when the div is the parent, but fails when meta is a 'top-level' element.